# How to update an SPFx solution

Tags: spfx-extensions

I am new to SPFx, and I was wondering how can we update the solution after packaging it for the first time?

Do I need to run the `gulp package-solution --ship` and add the **sppkg** file to SharePoint?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 2):

The build chain of an SPFX Project is the below:

1. `gulp bundle --ship`
2. `gulp package-solution --ship`

The above chain produces a set of files(js, manifests and the sppkg) that implement your solution.

In order to **upload** or **update** your solution, all you have to do is to upload the produced `sppkg file` to the `App Catalog` and the manifests/js to the `Cdn location` defined in `config\write-manifests.json` of the SPFX project.

It is good, in general terms, to version each build to be incremented by the feature that you are trying to introduce to the SPFX App, but in general, versioning will not stop the update procedure.

More on versioning [here](https://n8d.at/how-to-version-new-sharepoint-framework-projects)

*the upload of the js/manifests depends on the target version of SharePoint and if the flag `includeClientSiteAssets` is set to true (for example, SP2016 does not support it)

Comment: Something that i forgot is that you can use the `gulp clean` command to clean up old Build Files.

Comment: Be sure to check in the solution in the app catalog! Easy to miss on updates